# Adding custom rules in Solhint

Tags: solidity, static-code-analysis

I am using solhint plugin for linting solidity code. But I want to add custom rules for the code analysis. How to add custom rules as part of the ruleset ?

Code added for custom rule:

```
const BaseChecker = require('./../base-checker')

const ruleId = 'no-foos'
const meta = {
  type: 'naming',

  docs: {
    description: `Don't use Foo for Contract name`,
    category: 'Style Guide Rules'
  },

  isDefault: false,
  recommended: true,
  defaultSetup: 'warn',

  schema: null
}

class NoFoosAllowed extends BaseChecker {
  constructor(reporter) {
    super(reporter, ruleId, meta)
  }

  ContractDefinition(ctx) {
    const { name } = ctx

    if (name === 'Foo') {
      this.reporter.error(ctx, this.ruleId, 'Contracts cannot be named "Foo"')
    }
  }
}

module.exports = NoFoosAllowed
```

I have saved the above code into a new js file inside rules->naming folder. And i have used the 'no-foos' rule id inside my .solhint.json file inside the rules property.

```
{
    "extends": "solhint:all",
    "plugins": [],
    "rules": {
      "avoid-suicide": "error",
      "avoid-sha3": "warn",
      "no-foos" : "warn",
      "var-name-mixedcase": "error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each ruleset loops through all [rules](https://github.com/protofire/solhint/tree/master/lib/rules) and enables (or doesn't enable) it based on the [rule metadata](https://github.com/protofire/solhint/blob/master/lib/rules/order/func-order.js#L5) and the [ruleset config](https://github.com/protofire/solhint/blob/master/conf/rulesets/solhint-recommended.js#L7).

So you can create a custom rule in the `rules` folder and set it a combination of metadata that your ruleset will enable.

Comment: I have added a custom rule inside the rules->naming folder. But it not getting reflected while linting my sol file. Also i am getting "Rule doesn't exist" as warning.

Comment: @Nik Please edit your question and show how you added the rule and steps to reproduce the warning.